# Motivation behind the definition of compact sets.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A subset $K$ of a metric space $X$ is said to be compact if every open cover of $K$ contains a finite subcover.

I want to know what's the motivation for constructing such sets?

I know, this definition leads to lots of interesting result, yet how people arrived at such construction?

And, why open cover gets the priority? I mean, particularly, why open sets are chosen?

Comment: @ YuiTo Cheng, I read the answers there,but I am not satisfied with anyone of it.Can you give a more clear picture?

Comment: @Tom. Or [What was the motivation behind the open covering definition of compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179367/what-was-the-motivation-behind-the-open-covering-definition-of-compactness)